# Ideals are linearly ordered in evaluation rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, valuation-theory

How do I prove the fact that for any valuation ring $V$ the ideals are [totally ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) under inclusion?

Comment: What is your definition of a valuation ring?

Comment: @Bernard That V is a valuation ring if either x or x^-1 is contained in V where x is in its field of fractions F

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

- Prove first the principal ideal in $V$ are totally ordered by inclusion: for this, let $a,b\in V$. Show that if   $Va\not\subset Vb$, then $Vb\subset Va$.
- Deduce that, if $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b$ are two ideals in $V$, if  $\mathfrak a\not\subset \mathfrak b$, then $\mathfrak b\subset \mathfrak a$ (take $a\in\mathfrak a$, $\;a\notin\mathfrak b$. Show that, for any $b\in\mathfrak b$, $b\in Va$).

Comment: damn it why did you get banned I have questions to ask you on this post :(